# How do I create unique Sitecore JSS Dynamic Placeholders?

Tags: jss, dynamic-placeholder, nextjs

I have JSS Next.JS based component, I want to have 2 placeholders with the same key, but with a dynamic suffix. e.g. I need 2 equal columns.

```
<div>
  <Placeholder name='jss-6' rendering={rendering}/>
</div>
<div>
  <Placeholder name='jss-6' rendering={rendering}/>
</div>
```

My expectation is that that I will get 2 placeholders:

```
jss-6-{UID}-0
jss-6-{UID}-1
```

however, I get 2 placeholders with the same keys:

```
jss-6-{UID}-0
jss-6-{UID}-0
```

Is it expected behavior? How to overcome it and get different suffixes?

Edited:
Back to Sitecore MVC approach, it was possible to render few dynamic placeholders at once and suffixes were different. Also, it was possible to pass `seed` parameter, and suffix was started from that value. Is there something similar with JSS?

Comment: See my answer below to help you understand your situation. My question would be why you need same placeholder name within one rendering? What is use case?

Comment: @PeterProcházka
The use case is 2 columns layout with the same width.

Comment: Then you can elegantly solve this by introducing 2 placeholders - jss-right-column and jss-left-column

Comment: Yes, it is possible, it is my fallback plan.

I don't go with it initially, because it will double/triple/etc count of placeholders, which I don't want. That is why I am looking for a similar solution that was available with the MVC approach: pass placeholders count or pass seed.

Comment: This URL may help you for using dynamic placeholder with Sitecore JSS https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-dynamic-placeholders-and-jss.html

Comment: @RishirajShekhawat

Thank you, I have read it. I want to be the last suffix to be unique, but it is always 0. And it looks like, it is not possible to achieve it in the current version.

Comment: The UIDs are the same?

Comment: @MStodd UIDs are different, but the "numbering" suffix is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behaviour of dynamic placeholders.

Key that is generated `jss-6-{UID}-0` is not a key of placeholder. That is key of component within layout. Sitecore will know to which placeholder and component to put that rendering based on this.

Let's split the key:

- jss-6 - placeholder name
- UID - Unique ID of rendering that contains placeholder
- 0 - index suffix

If you add another component to your first placeholder, it will get expected `jss-6-{UID}-1` with 1 as suffix.

Index suffix always starts from 0 as default seed value.

Each independent call of Placeholder knows nothing about each other. That's why if you insert two dynamic placeholders with the same name into the same rendering, you will get a collision.

Take a look in official Sitecore documentation about more information on dynamic placeholders: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/dynamic-placeholders.html

Comment: My question is how to pass something like a seed in JSS+Next.JS

As there is no `seed` prop in Placeholder.